Amending default template for Extension: Bootstrap 5 Quick Snipppets by Anbuselvan Rocky
I am new to VS Code and want to amend the default template for the extension: Bootstrap 5 Quick Snippets. Any guidance in the right direction shall be highly appreciated.
